# order of evaluation of function parameters

Tags: c++, c, function, operator-precedence

What will be printed as the result of the operation below:

```
x=5; 
printf("%d,%d,%d\n",x,x<<2,x>>2);
```

Answer: 5,20,1

I thought order is undefined yet I found above as interview question on many sites.

Comment: thanks for help with indentation . And I meant some operator like postfix or prefix instead of shift.

Comment: Why exactly do you think it'd be undefined? and why do you think order of evaluation matters?  Each parameter will have the same value regardless of when it is evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C++ standard:

> The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. All side effects of argument expression evaluations take effect before the function is entered. The order of evaluation of the postfix expression and the argument expression list is unspecified.

However, your example would only have undefined behavior if the arguments were `x>>=2` and `x<<=2`, such that x were being modified.

Comment: in case of `>>=` and `<<=` it would be undefined, not ambiguous

Comment: Ambiguity is orthogonal. The real issue is _undefinedness_.

Answer (score 3):

Bit shift operators don't modify the value of the variable... so order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

The *order of evaluation* is unspecified, but it doesn't matter because you're not modifying `x` at all.

So the program is well-defined, and the answer is as given.

The following would have undefined semantics:

```
printf("%d,%d,%d\n", x, x <<= 2, x >>= 2);
```

Comment: ALthough I don't see a downvote on your answer I can suppose it was there and the only thing I can think of is that as we discussed the behavior is not unspecified, but undefined, which makes your answer not-entirely correct... But I wouldn't downvote just for that

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [c++ standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf).

Paragraph 5.2.2.8:

> The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. All side effects
>   of argument expression evaluations take effect before the function is
>   entered. The order of evaluation of the postfix expression and the
>   argument expression list is unspecified.

In other words, It depends on compiler only.

Answer (score -1):

The order of evaluation is undefined in the Official C Specification.

However, as a matter of practicality, parameters are usually evaluated right-to-left.

In your problem, the bit-shift operator doesn't change the value of X, so the order of evaluation is not important.  You'd get 5,20,1, whether evaluated left-to-right, right-to-left, or middle-first.

In C, parameters are **pushed** on to the stack in a right-to-left order, so that the 1st param (in this case, the char* "%d,%d,%d") is at the top of the stack.  Parameters are usually (but not always) evaluated in the same order they are pushed.

A problem that better illustrates what you're talking about is:

```
int i=1;
printf("%d, %d, %d", i++, i++, i++);
```

The *official* answer is "undefined".
The practical answer, (in the several compilers/platforms I've tried), is "3, 2, 1".

Comment: Then you have very limited experience. Also once the compiler optimizations get a hold of if then there is no telling what will happen.

Comment: All this pretending that you know what the compiler is doing is _dangerous_. (a) Don't do it; (b) **please** for the love of god don't teach it.

Comment: Strange, in all the implementations I've tried, your example gives "3, 3, 3".  Granted, I only tested three implementations (msvc10, MingW(gcc 4.5.4) and [Ideone(gcc 4.3.4)](http://ideone.com/LNR8s)), but they are quite widely used implementations.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: I would also bet that you could get the values to change by using different optimizations.