# array manipulation results

Tags: c, arrays

can someone provide me more insight on why this code works the way it works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
     printf("%d,%d \n",i[a],i[a]++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
2,1 
3,2 
4,3 
5,4 
6,5
```

Thanks

Comment: Where did you find that code? If it's in a book, please stop reading, it's hurting you. `i[a]++` is just plain evil.

Comment: its a quiz sort of thing. I havent seen that in any book and thats why I reached out to the folks here.

Comment: It does not have "void main()" so it cannot be Herb Schildt ;-)

Comment: Before anyone wonders why it's `index[array]` instead of `array[index]` and still works (well, *that* part works - the program as a whole has UB), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a.

Comment: @delnan : +1 for getting to the heart of it :)

Comment: so a followup question - Is this seen commonly (cause this is the first time I have faced/seen this) and does it happen for any function or printf() in particular

Comment: @KeithThompson: a professor asked it.

Comment: Painfully ugly code like that is more commonly seen than it should be, but not all *that* often.  The problem is going to occur any time one function argument modifies an object and another reads it.  ***So don't do that.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is undefined.

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5p2:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value  shall be read only to determine the
>   value to be stored.

The program both modifies `i[a]` (in `i[a]++`) and reads its value (in the next argument), and the result of reading the value is not used to determine the value to be stored.

This is not *just* a matter of the unspecified order of evaluation of function arguments; the fact that there's no sequence point between `i[a]++` and `i[a]` (since that's not a comma *operator*) means that the behavior, not just the result, is undefined.

Comment: Which means trying to figure out *why* you get a particular result is largely a waste of time; it can vary based on platform, compiler, compiler settings, surrounding code, etc.  Whether by accident or design, whatever the compiler does *at that particular moment* is "okay".

Comment: Well, it can sometimes be useful to diagnose why a program is producing a particular result.  The ideal solution, of course, is to fix the code, but that can be a very involved process.

Comment: To be fair, some others actually answered the question more directly than I did.

Comment: From _What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior_ series at the LLVM Project Blog, "any undefined behavior in C gives license to the implementation (the compiler and runtime) to produce code that formats your hard drive, does completely unexpected things, or worse." http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: I upvoted for, "This is not just a matter of the unspecified order of evaluation of function arguments; ... " I don't think the other answers made that clear.

Answer (score 2):

It works by undefined behaviour. The order of evaluation of function arguments is not defined. The comma is not a sequence point.

EDIT: ooops, I read to fast. There is only one write to the a[i] object, so the behaviour is not undefined, only the results.

Comment: "The comma is not a sequence point." is correct in context, but can be misunderstood so I plea for clarification. The comma *operator*, which is very much seperate from the comma in argument lists, parameter lists, etc. *is* a sequence point. That's it's main use.

Comment: Sorry. I just corrected it. I meant: **this** comma. But that's not the real issue. The real issue is order of evaluation of function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

"i[a]++" is a post increment, so it will return the value of i[a] and then increment i[a] right away.

In your case, the third parameter of printf gets evaluated before the second (the evaluation order of function parameters is unspecified as far as I know), and thus the second parameter returns the already incremented value.

Comment: The question I am asking is why.

Comment: This has got me curious too - will every compiler evaluate right-to-left ?

Comment: @spad6: why what ? About the evaluation order of parameters, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725706/order-of-evaluation-of-function-parameters : the standard says it's unspecified and it will thus depend on your compiler.

Comment: @HughJones: They may, but are not required to by the standard. See answers to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c

Comment: @Shannon - and I expect they dont

Comment: @Hugh: even if most of them do, it's better to expect nothing of it. It's always bad to rely on undefined behaviors ^^

Comment: @Shautieh - I can see that.  My question 'will every compiler ...' was rhetorical

Comment: @Hugh Jones: Ah, I didn't take it as rhetorical.