# C/C++ - evaluation of the arguments in a function call

Tags: c++, c, semantics, multiplatform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [order of evaluation of function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725706/order-of-evaluation-of-function-parameters)

Is it safe to use the following construction in C/C++?

```
f(g(), h());
```

where `g()` is expected to be evaluated **first**, then `h()`.

Do all compilers show the same behavior on all architectures?

Comment: This question is asked so often here, I can't decide which one to chose for a duplicate marker...

Comment: Thx, but what about real-world compilers? What order do they use?

Comment: @psihodelia: I have seen every order to be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NO! There is no guarantee what order these are carried out in. Only that both g() and h() are carried out before f().
See this: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm
I think there's an updated C++11 version of that, I'll have a look.

Edit: C++11 version http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/

Edit 2: If you really want to know what specific compilers do, try this: http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf
Section 7 (page 16) may be relevant, though it's a bit over my head, but for instance __cdecl calling convention means arguments are passed from right to left (at least stored that way), whereas for __fastcall "The first two DWORD or smaller arguments are passed in ECX and EDX registers; all other arguments are passed right to left." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

So it does vary for different compilers.

**Much later edit**: It turns out that for constructors using the initializer list syntax (curly braces `{}`), order of evaluation *is* guaranteed (even if it is a call to a constructor that does not take a `std::initializer_list`. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058592/how-to-guarantee-order-of-argument-evaluation-when-calling-a-function-object).

Answer (score 1):

See 1.9 Program execution:

> Certain other aspects and operations of the abstract machine are described in this International Standard as
>   unspecified (**for example, order of evaluation of arguments to a function**). Where possible, this International
>   Standard defines a set of allowable behaviors.

and 8.3.6 Default arguments, 9:

> [...] Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called. The order of evaluation of function
>   arguments is unspecified. Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in a default argument,
>   even if they are not evaluated. [...]

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not safe - if you need a guaranteed order of evaluation, e.g. because of side effects, then you will need to do something like this:

```
foo = g();
bar = h();
f(foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the order of evaluation of arguments with respect to each other is unspecified. The only guarantee that you have is that they will not be executed concurrently with each other.

Comment: [Where does that guarantee come from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443532/could-a-c-implementation-in-theory-parallelise-the-evaluation-of-two-functio)

Answer (score 0):

No.
The standard don't define the order of evaluation in that case, and each compiler may do whatever it wants.
I think that most of them (and specially `gcc`) evaluate the rightest first.

Comment: Depending on optimization flags (and the target hardware).