# Order of function calls in variadic template expansion

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I've found code in an open source project that basically looks like this:

```
template< typename... Args >
void expand_calls_hack(Args&&... args)
{}

template <unsigned int... Indices>
struct foo
{
  static void bar(some_tuple_type& t)
  {
    meta::expand_calls_hack((std::get<Indices>(t).doSomething(), 0)...);
  }
};
```

I figured this "construct" is used to call `doSomething()` for each of the tuple elements. However, it seems to me that the order of the calls to `doSomething()` is undefined, at least it would be with normal functions in C++03. This would be a bug, since the calls have side effects. I have two questions about this:

1. What is the use of the (tupleElement.doSomething(), 0) - Is that the comma operator? I gather that it has something to do with using expand_calls_hack to expand the calls.
2. How can this be fixed so that the calls are evaluated left-to-right? Note that I need that to compile on VC2013. I've tried expanding a list of lambdas and calling it sequentially, but I could not get that to compile.

I hope I've not left out too much context, but for the curious, the source of this code is [on github here, line 419](https://github.com/decimad/luabind-deboostified/blob/master/luabind/detail/call.hpp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first part of the question is quite simple: `std::get<I>(t).doSomething()` may return `void`. As a result, you can't directly use this expression as an argument to `expand_calls_hack()`. Using the comma operator arranges for an argument to be present even if `doSomething()` returns `void`.

The order of function evaluations when invoking a variadic function template is not special, i.e., the evaluation order is undefined. However, it turns out that the order of evaluation of constructor arguments when using brace initialization *is* defined (see, e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058592/how-to-guarantee-order-of-argument-evaluation-when-calling-a-function-object)). That is, you can guarantee the order of evaluation using something like this:

```
namespace meta {
    struct order {
        template <typename... T>
        order(T&&...) {}
    };
}
// ...
template <unsigned int... Indices>
struct foo
{
    template <typename T>
    static void bar(T&& t)
    {
        meta::expand_calls_hack((std::get<Indices>(t).doSomething(), 0)...);
        meta::order{(std::get<Indices>(t).doSomething(), 0)...};
    }
};
```

In the above function the use of `expand_calls_hack()` evaluates the expressions back to front on my system while the use of `order` evaluates them front to back as it has to. I think a similar effect can be achieved using an `std::initializer_list<int>` which would have the need effect of not requiring a variadic template: the arguments are all `int`s anyway:

```
namespace meta {
    struct init_order {
        init_order(std::initializer_list<int>) {}
    };
}
```

It would be used exactly the same as `meta::order`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well! Just out of curiosity, can I get rid of the the init_order type in the second example and just use `std::initializer_list<int>{/*calls to expand here*/}`?

Comment: I don't think `std::initializer_list<T>` has such a constructor. It is something magical which the compiler knows how to fill.

Comment: @DietmarKühl You can do `std::initializer_list<int> i = {1, 2, 3};`. Also, a `(void)` cast on the result of `doSomething()` would be necessary in highly generic code.

Comment: @T.C.: returning `void` seems to be quite common. Overloading the comma operator is, fortunately rather uncommon and whether this use needs to be support is somewhat questionable. However, I only addressed the questions actually asked. It is useful to knw that an `std::initializer_list<int>` could be used. I guess now `i` needs to be used to acoid a warning.

Comment: It has to be brace initalization it seems, using the new c++17 feature of not having to provide the type, you can directly write `return std::tuple{do_something<I>()...};` Using  `return std::tuple(do_something<I>()...);` does not guarantee the order (at least on VS19...