# How to append an element to an array c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a for loop that adds an integer value to an array. I know in python it is as simple as x.append() but I want to know how I would append a value in c++ to an array?

Comment: ¿What is an 'array' for you?

Comment: a list .. some like  arra[4];

Comment: Here there is an insightful solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/41398948/4743711

Answer (score 6):

Use a `std::vector<T>`, and call [`v.push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Arrays in C++ cannot change their size.

Comment: Hey thank you! Wanted to know what the T was used for in between "<>" and the "v." in push_back()?

Comment: It's a template parameter.  You pass a type there, like `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<std::string>`.