# Why to std::forward a callable before calling it?

Tags: c++, c++11

Often people `std::forward` a callable object before calling it like this ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14058638/8414561)):

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
void call(F &&f, Args &&...args)
{
    std::forward<F>(f) ( // <<< -- question
        std::forward<Args>(args)...  
    );
}
```

What's the benefit of `std::forward`-ing `f` in the example above compared to simple `f(std::forward<Args>(args)...`?